# how to populate google map marker using JSON and JSP

Tags: ajax, json, google-maps, jsp

I have searched this tutorial from internet. I have found some solutions with php. They said we can populate google map marker from database saved longitude and latitude using JSON. these tutorials are based on php. I want to do this with JSP. how can I do that? any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the Google Map API works with JavaScript. There is noting special for JSP.

First you have to learn about how to add a single marker on Google Map then simply iterate all the Markers details from JSON, create that much of Markers and simply add them to the Google Map.

It's worth reading tutorial on [Google Map - Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

---

The below sample code is picked from [Google Map Tutorial - Simple markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple markers</title>
<style>
html,body,#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {

        var json = [
                {
                    "title" : "Stockholm",
                    "lat" : 59.3,
                    "lng" : 18.1,
                    "description" : "Stockholm is the capital and the largest city of Sweden and constitutes the most populated urban area in Scandinavia with a population of 2.1 million in the metropolitan area (2010)"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Oslo",
                    "lat" : 59.9,
                    "lng" : 10.8,
                    "description" : "Oslo is a municipality, and the capital and most populous city of Norway with a metropolitan population of 1,442,318 (as of 2010)."
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Copenhagen",
                    "lat" : 55.7,
                    "lng" : 12.6,
                    "description" : "Copenhagen is the capital of Denmark and its most populous city, with a metropolitan population of 1,931,467 (as of 1 January 2012)."
                } ];

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.3, 18.1);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom : 3,
            center : myLatlng
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);

        for ( var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
            var data = json[i], latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat,
                    data.lng);

            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : latLng,
                map : map,
                title : data.title
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
        }

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

snapshot:

[image]